# How does NodeJS handles primitives and objects in multi user environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am use to Javascript on the client. So if I have this:

```
var myNumber = 10;
```

It is easy for me to understand that client's browser holds this variable.

In nodeJS however the code runs for multiple users and my understanding of how this works is not complete. For instance, in this simplified code:

```
var parser = require('./parser');

api.on('message', function (messageJson) {      

        var myNumber = 10;

        parser.parse(messageJson);
});
```

To my understanding, the "myNumber" variable is still per invokation as it lives within the scope of the "api.on" method which runs separately for each execution. However what about the "parser" object? is the same instance available for all the processes?

Is there a difference when I run it like this:

```
api.on('message', function (messageJson) {      

        var parser = require('./parser');
        var myNumber = 10;

        parser.parse(messageJson);
});
```

and if I do run it like this, and there is a difference, can I now use "global" variables within the scope the 'parser' module which will be different for every execution?

Comment: it depends on the implementation of `parser`. it may hold a state, it may not. when you think about it, it's like this on every platform/programing language. an instnace may be linked to some previous state, it may be completly unrelated entity.

Comment: Nodejs does not know about users. Everything depends on your `api` implementation, does it fire separate messages for separate users? And how is a "user" identified in the callback?

Comment: I am building a bot for Telegram Messenger which "talks" to multiple users. Every time a user sends the bot a message the api is invoked with  a messageJson (which contains the userId). For now I manually parse the message and handle the sessions. Not ideal, as restarting the NodeJS will erase the session memory but for now its a known issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference when I run `require` every time? 
>   Can I now use "global" variables within the scope the 'parser' module which will be different for every execution?

No, there is no difference. Node does cache modules, and regardless how many times your `require('parser')` you will always get the same object (unless you mess with the module cache, of course).